# How to get multiple pages under same URL in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, multipage

I've made a large shiny app that uses brochure that connects other pages, where users can click on links to get to different interactive pages. Each page is extensive with multiple tabs, the links to the other pages, and interactive data displays.

When uploading to shiny the package I have only allows 1 URL. It will not even publish the app as it can tell it contains multiple URLs. Is there a way to still publish this through multiple apps, or is there another way to connect all these pages that doesn't require a change to the URL used while still running all components well?

I am not able to upgrade to the very expensive professional account, so any options would be greatly appreciated, even if it means publishing to a different website than shinyapps.io.